# The default behaviour of mat select changes when I add a search bar

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

So below is my code. What I am doing is showing all the available devices in a dropdown where multi select is allowed and also I have added a search field when devices count is more than 4. The default behaviour of mat-select is that when I select an option and close the dropdown, it opens on the selected option when I reopen it. But here it's not happening. It starts from the start. So I want that when I scroll and select last option, and when I reopen the dropdown the menu should be scrolled enough to show me the selected option.
Is this default behaviour not working because I added a search bar?

```html
<form [formGroup]="gatewayForm" autocomplete="off">
                        <mat-form-field style="font-size:0.83em" class="no-arrow activity-log-field">
                            <mat-select formControlName="gatewayCtrl" multiple disableOptionCentering panelClass="form-panel gpanel" name="Gateway" (openedChange)="checkChanged($event,'gatewayList')" (selectionChange)="gatewaySelectedClick($event)">
                                <mat-select-trigger>
                                    {{selectedText}}
                                    <span *ngIf="extratext!=null" class="example-additional-selection">
                                        {{extratext}}
                                    </span>
                                </mat-select-trigger>
                                
                                <mat-form-field *ngIf="gateways && gateways.length>4" class="organistation-searchField" appearance="outline"  [floatLabel]="'never'" aria-autocomplete="off" style="padding: 5px 8px 5px 8px;font-size: 13px">
                                    <input #search autocomplete="off" formControlName="searchTerm" (keyup)="filterDevices($event.target.value,'gatewayList','gpanel');" (keydown)="$event.stopPropagation()" matInput placeholder="Search Device">
                                    <mat-icon matSuffix style="color:#24539f;position: relative;top: 0.1em;">search</mat-icon>
                                </mat-form-field>
                                <div class="panel-optn" style="max-height: 170px;">
                                    <mat-option *ngIf="gateways && gateways.length>1" (click)="toggleAllSelection()" #allSelected class="gatewayList" [value]="allgateways">All devices</mat-option>
                                    <mat-option (click)="tosslePerOne(allSelected!=null?allSelected.viewValue:null)" class="gatewayList" *ngFor="let gateway of gateways" [value]="gateway">
                                        {{ gateway.panel_name }}
                                    </mat-option>
                                </div>
                            </mat-select>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.yourElementHere.focus();
```

this should focus the dropdown on the element you select.

include the value of your selected option like

```
this.yourElementHere.focus(selectedOption);
```

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was caused by the mat-option being inside a div tag. I removed it and applied the styling on the mat-select directly through panelClass.